# From a random sequence, make appear an specific answer 5 times

Tags: python-3.x

I am implementing an [N-back task with visual stimuli.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-back)

The stimuli is going to appear 20 times (randomly), but the correct answer must appear 5 times.

To generate a random sequence I can use "randint". But how can I tell to python to generate 5 times the correct answer.

Example of a 0-back. 
The circle appears 20 times, but only 5 times it is the same as what it is needed.
[image]

Comment: You could populate a list with random numbers except the solution and then put the solution 5 times in random or fixed locations?

Answer (score 0):

So, I created 2 arrays.

right_answer, contains the position that I want to repeat 4 times.

wrong_answers, contains the other 8 positions. Each one repeats twice.

I concatenated them and then applied a permutation with a seed. With this, the array will be permuted but I will assure that the specific position/answer appear 4 times.

```
right_answer = np.array([[510,642],[510,642],\
                        [510,642],[510,642]])


wrong_answers = np.array([[510,382],[510,512],\
                  [640,382],[640,512],[640,642],\
                  [770,382],[770,512],[770,642],\
                  [510,382],[510,512],\
                  [640,382],[640,512],[640,642],\
                  [770,382],[770,512],[770,642]])


concat=np.concatenate((right_answer, wrong_answers))
positions = np.random.RandomState(seed=42).permutation(concat)

print (positions)
```